# How to loop an event every 2 hours Discord Py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I basically want to loop this event every 2 hours so the bot will change pfp every 2 hours, but i can't find any way to do it. I already tried trask.loop but i'm confuse with that one

```
pfp_pics = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
random_pfp = random.choice(pfp_pics)    
pfp_path = "pfp/{}.png".format(random_pfp)

fp = open(pfp_path, 'rb')
pfp = fp.read()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.user.edit(avatar=pfp)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of using a task loop:

```py
async def my_task():
    cur_avatar = 0
    while True:
        prev_avatar = cur_avatar
        while cur_avatar == prev_avatar:
            cur_avatar = random.randint(0, 7) # ensure same avatar isn't picked
        pfp = open(f"pfp/{cur_avatar}.png", "rb").read()
        await client.user.edit(avatar=pfp)
        await asyncio.sleep(7200)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")
    client.loop.create_task(my_task())
```

---

**References:**

- [`ClientUser.edit()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.ClientUser.edit)
- [`asyncio.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task)
- [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep)
- [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint)

Comment: It work, thanks. One thing to say is the line 
"while cur_avatar != prev_avatar:" . that basically says 0 != 0 so that'd instatly cancel the cur_avatar = random.randint(0, 7). So i just changed it to cur_avatar == prev_avatar. But beyond that. The code works perfect. Thank you

Comment: Ah yeah, good catch! Just edited it. Glad you got it working! Best of luck with the bot :)

Answer (score -1):

maybe you could set a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) that invokes a python script every 2 hours?

Is trask loop a typo?  Couldn't find anything about that on google.

I'm not entirely familiar with how Discord.py works, but you if there's an event loop, you can poll to check whether 2 hours is up yet.  i.e. save the time of the last event, either to a variable in the python script, or to a file, and every iteration of the event loop, check to see if `datetime.now()` has passed the time to do the thing, and if it has, then do the thing and update the time of last event.